# Printing specific values of a dictionary while iterating through keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, printing, nested

```
nested_dict = {'dictA': {'dict0': {'key0' : 'value0',
                                   'key1' : 'value1',
                                   'key2' : 'value2'
                                   ...
                                  },
                        {'dict1': {'key0' : 'value0',
                                   'key1' : 'value1',
                                   'key2' : 'value2'
                                    ...
                                  },
                         ...
               ...
              }
```

Using a nested dictionary like this example, whats the best way to print:

```
[dictA]
[dictA][dict0][key2] , [dictA][dict1][key1] : ([dictA][dict1][key5] / [dictA][dict1][key4]) 
[dictA][dict1][key2] , [dictA][dict1][key1] : ([dictA][dict1][key5] / [dictA][dict1][key4])
[dictA][dict(...)][key2] , [dictA][dict1][key1] : ([dictA][dict1][key5] / [dictA][dict1[key4])
...
```

Currently I've been trying:

```
        def catalogFormat(dct):
        for key, value in dct.items():

            #TODO: List Iteration needs to be one time, but all instances

            if isinstance(value, dict):
                print('| ', key, ' |')
                catalogFormat(value)
                print('| ', ' |')
            else:
                print('| ', dct.get(key2), ', ',dct.get(key1), ': ' (dct.get(key5)/dct.get(key4)))
```

My goal is to iterate through each nested dict and produce a printout of specific keys until all of them have been printed.

Comment: what you want to print is not clear.

Comment: I want to iterate through a dictionary, printing nested keys and values until the whole dictionary is printed.